# How do I print the result of an objective-c class method in gdb?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, gdb

When using gdb (via the debug console) to debug an iPad program in Xcode 4, I'm trying to print out the result of running a class method:

```
(gdb) po [MyClass foo:@"bar"]
```

gdb outputs the following:

> > No symbol "MyClass" in current context.

Is there some way to print the result of `+(NSString *)foo:(NSString *)string` using gdb in Xcode 4?

Comment: Having no issues. Just put a breakpoint in the init method of a class. And POed a class method with a string. Which Version and which compiler did you use?

Comment: I actually think what you've posted works. Are you sure 'MyClass' is loaded at the point you use 'po'?

Comment: @Nick Weaver - I'm using LLVM compiler 2.0.

Comment: @Tejas - see my comment below Joe's answer. I was able to run class methods on classes that have instances. MyClass did not have any instances and apparently was optimized out of the lookup symbols as a result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you have not declared anything of type `MyClass` in your targets source. If your `MyClass` is only designed to have static methods you can try something like

```
#if DEBUG //gdb Static Method Fix
    MyClass *mc = nil;  //This makes the symbol available
    [mc class];         //supress unused warning
#endif
```

My guess is that by not declaring a type of the class anywhere in your code it has been optimized out of the lookup symbols. From my testing that call above does not even have to be called for it to work. If you look at [printcmd.c of gdb](http://opensource.apple.com/source/gdb/gdb-1469/src/gdb/printcmd.c) line # 1250 this is where the error is printed from and this occurs after a call to lookup_minimal_symbol. And although gdb is unable to find the symbol in context it is still fine to only use static methods of `MyClass` in your source code without the fix above.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I was able to successfully print the result of the class method by adding the above code, and also changing the Code Generation Optimization Level in the project build settings to None [-O0]. Each of these individually did not solve the problem, but together they do.

Comment: Ah yes good point, by default my Debug optimization level is set None [-O0].

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8220978/784318). The solution in my case was to use `NSClassFromString` like this:

```
po [NSClassFromString(@"MyClass") foo:@"bar"]
```

Comment: A little nicer than Joe’s answer, as you don’t have to compile in some additional code first.

Comment: I noticed that on OS X, `NSClassFromString` (or an explict declaration as in the other answer) is required when debugging 32-bit but not 64-bit binaries.