# Access static Method in GDB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, gdb

I recently discovered the GDB in Xcode which makes up for some functionality which IMHO seems to be lacking in Xcode.

So I can do the following in GDB:

```
(gdb) po [LoginManager sharedSession].loginToken
20D52FE9-3573-437E-9A65-846572B63726
```

However, I have another Service class, which is currently not loaded so I get the following error:

```
(gdb) po [SessionService displaySessionInfoForToken:@"XXX"]
No symbol "SessionService" in current context.
```

I don't understand why the `LoginManager` can be loaded but not the `SessionService`.

Comment: In order to globally load the `SessionService` I tried to include it in `MyProject_Prefix.pch` but this did not fix the issue.

Comment: Are you certain the `displaySessionForToken` is a *class* method and not an *instance* method?

Comment: @trojanfoe Positive it is a class method: `+ (NSSTring *)displaySessionInfoForToken:(NSString *) token;`

Comment: Is there maybe some import functionality for GDB to load the class into its current context?

Comment: Yeah just looking into that.  This is a good question :) +1

Comment: There is a `ptype` command which prints a type definition; can you try that on `SessionService` before the `po`?

Comment: Potentially a duplication of [this one][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783340/how-do-i-print-the-result-of-an-objective-c-class-method-in-gdb

Comment: @trojanfoe I get the same '... not in context ...' error  when I run ptype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using NSClassFromString, like this:

```
(gdb) po [NSClassFromString(@"SessionService") displaySessionInfoForToken:@"XXX"]
```

It's hard to say exactly what's going on, but using NSClassFromString may tickle the right thing in the runtime to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. I guess the problem is that the class is not loaded in GDB. The other class which was known was probably loaded at some point before and was therefore known to GDB. The Approach is a little more verbose using NSClassFromString but that's fine.